# how does add123.com get their data?

Tags: government

add123.com (d/b/a AutoDataDirect, Inc) lets you look up vehicle registration information with a license plate number. That information is protected under the Federal Driver's Privacy Protection Act, however, I'm not interested in that information myself. I just want to know how they got it. Like who they contacted, how they proved that they were authorized to have that information, etc.

The reason I want to know this is that my employer does auto refinance. They're a client of add123.com already and I'm thinking that they could save money if they just got that information themselves instead of going through a third party.

Thus far I've tried open record requests to Texas Department of Motor Vehicles (TxDMV), Vehicle Titles and Registration (VTR) Division and the Texas Attorney General (in the off chance that any appeals were filed) but neither of them have had any correspondence with add123.com.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

From [add123.com NMVTIS page](http://add123.com/autodata/nmvtis):

> The National Motor Vehicle Title Information System (NMVTIS) is a federal database containing automobile information from states, insurance carriers and the salvage industry. The vehicle history information is available to the public, and can provide valuable information about a potential purchase.

The problem with cars is that they can be easily moved around, so being able to find registration history from the Texas DMV will only give you details for Texas cars, and not cars that were flooded in Lousiana, or something.

An alteranative to add123.com would be to contact each State's DMV. Here is the PDF list of contact info - [LINK](http://www.aamva.org/WorkArea/linkit.aspx?LinkIdentifier=id&ItemID=2701&libID=2687).

Answer (score 1):

Tx DPS sells 'credits' to legally qualified business/individuals to get the reg info direct but only Texas. Accounts would need to be established with other states, some aren't accessible - ADD123 is easier and cheaper in the long run.